# Manual PowerShell DSC module installation

Tags: dsc, powershell-v4.0

I am working on servers without access to the Internet. I am uploading DSC modules to the server, E.g. AccessControlDSC.

The modules are being installed in `c:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`

I unzip AccessControlDSC into the modules folder which adds:

`AccessControlDSC\1.1.0.0\<modulefiles>`

If I run `Get-DscResource` The AccessControlDSC module does not show.

If I change the folder structure to:

`AccessControlDSC\<modulefiles>`

And then run `Get-DscResource` the AccessControlDSC module **does** show.

The servers are Windows 2012R2 running PowerShell v4. For installing modules, does the version folder need to be removed so they are seen correctly by PowerShell V4? I have looked on PowerShell v5.1 machines and the version folder doesn't seem to pose an issue.

I am having a hard time finding references for the proper layout. Most searches seem to refer to `Install-Module` or `PowerShellGet` which isn't an option currently.

Comment: Have you ever solved this? I'm also wondering about the same thing.

Comment: Hi @kevindd992002 welcome to Stack. No, I never did figure this out and haven't administered Windows boxes for more than a year now.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the version folder needs to be removed for PS v4. This means that you can only have one version of the resource module in PS v4.